# CGIR assertion 'fitsType<size_t>()' failed

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink model that I'm trying to generate to a C++ dll. I've successfully compiled similar models, but this one is giving me the following errors:

```
CGIR assertion 'fitsType<size_t>()' failed in 'b:\matlab\derived\win32\src\include\cg_ir\util_prim\../../../../../../src/cg_ir/export/include/cg_ir/util_prim/Size64.hpp:125'
[  0] 0x5d20bde3            C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\cg_ir.dll+00769507 ( CG::Scope::treeStackSize+000019 )
[  1] 0x5d200b68            C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\cg_ir.dll+00723816 ( CG::Fcn::stackSize+000024 )
[  2] 0x590d36e2       C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\cgir_xform.dll+02242274 ( CG::EnforceStackLimit::getFcnStackSize+000034 )
[  3] 0x590d390a       C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\cgir_xform.dll+02242826 ( CG::EnforceStackLimit::initialize_fcn_stack_size_info+000234 )
[  4] 0x590d42bb       C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\cgir_xform.dll+02245307 ( CG::EnforceStackLimit::EnforceStackLimit+000219 )
[  5] 0x59384cc2            C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\rtwcg.dll+00806082 ( RTWCG::getBlockParameterURLString+004434 )
[  6] 0x59385e3b            C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\rtwcg.dll+00810555 ( RTWCG::getBlockParameterURLString+008907 )
[  7] 0x593706f1            C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\rtwcg.dll+00722673 ( RTWCG::RTWFcnConst::OptimizeAndEmitCode+007777 )
[  8] 0x5933085d            C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\rtwcg.dll+00460893 ( RTWCG::RTWCGModule::OptimizeAndEmitCode+000125 )
[  9] 0x5a6f9ecd    C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\libmwsimulink.dll+08298189 ( BlockSetCheckVarDimsInputEmpty+066381 )
[ 10] 0x5a6f6f97    C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\libmwsimulink.dll+08286103 ( BlockSetCheckVarDimsInputEmpty+054295 )
[ 11] 0x5a74aa02    C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\libmwsimulink.dll+08628738 ( sleGetRTWBlockForSLBlock+262210 )
[ 12] 0x5a74af9f    C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\libmwsimulink.dll+08630175 ( sleGetRTWBlockForSLBlock+263647 )
[ 13] 0x5a23b9c5    C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\libmwsimulink.dll+03324357 ( ArrayToSLObject+481685 )
[ 14] 0x025dea8c     C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\m_dispatcher.dll+00060044 ( mdLogging::log_function_exit+000108 )
[ 15] 0x025de561     C:\MATLABR2011b_x86\bin\win32\m_dispatcher.dll+00058721 ( Mfunction_handle::dispatch+000401 )
### Build procedure for model: 'vcts_auxiSns' aborted due to an error.
```

I also get the following error message in a dialog box:

```
Unexpected or internal error encountered in "in CGIR: b:\matlab\derived\win32\src\include\cg_ir\util_prim\../../../../../../src/cg_ir/export/include/cg_ir/util_prim/Size64.hpp line 125: fitsType<size_t>()
". Please report this to MathWorks if you can cause it to recur
```

---

UPDATE:

I have now been able to locate the problem, and it seems there is a problem with a specific signal. The image below shows a small part of a subsystem, and whenever one of the three signals in the red box is allowed to flow, the model can't be code generated. As soon as I disrupt all three signals, the code generation works.

[image: Part of the model where the error arise]
Unfortunately, I haven't been able to solve the problem, so I'm still eager to hear any and all suggestions!

Comment: How big is your model?

Comment: It's not too big (I've compiled bigger models before), but the inputs to some of the matlab function blocks are quite substantial. I'm beginning to suspect that those could be a problem.

Comment: If it is not too large then try deleting what you can and send the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug with the signal propagation in the code generation in Matlab 2011b. According to Mathworks it was solved in 2012a and later, so I updated to 2013b. Now I don't get that error any longer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if it gives you this kind of error, what you do is delete the folders slprj and the "programName_etl_hrt" folders where you compiled or tried to compile and it won't give you that error anymore.

I've had this error a few times, you just need to delete those folders, don't worry simulink will regenerate them again for you